# create dictionary with multiple keys and values

Tags: python

I would like to create a dictionary with multiple keys and values. At this point I am not sure that I am putting my question correctly. But here is an example of what I want to create :

```
patDct = {
           'mkey1':{'key1':'val_a1', 'key2':'val_a2', 'key3':'val_a3'},
           'mkey2':{'key1':'val_b1', 'key2':'val_b2', 'key3':'val_b3'},
           ....
          }
```

I have two dictionaries and I am pulling information for 'mkey*', and 'val*' from them. 'key*' are strings.

I have a piece of code to create the dictionary without the 'mkey*', but that only prints out the last set of values. Following is what I have now.
"storedct" and "datadct" are two given dictionaries. 
Here I would like 'mkey*' to get the value of "item".

```
 patDct = dict()                                                                                                                                                             
 for item in storedct :                                                                                                                                                         
     for pattern in datadct :                                                                                                                                                    
         if pattern in item :                                                                                                                                                     
             patDct['key1'] = datadct[pattern]["dpath"]                                                                                                        
             patDct['key2'] = datadct[pattern]["mask"]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
             patDct['key3'] = storedct[item]
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What you show is called a nested dictionary. Also, we'll understand your code better if you show the contents of your dictionaries. Right now we can see the desired output, but not input.

Comment: If you can write storedct and datadct in terms of key*, val* and mkey* that would really help!

Comment: storedct = {'val_a1' : 'val_a2', 'val_b1':'val_b2',....}
datadct is nested dictionary with *mkey* as a pattern inside that...

Answer (score 1):

```
 patDct = dict()    
 n=1                                                                                                                                                        
 for item in storedct :
     patDct["mkey%s"%n] = {}
     p =  patDct["mkey%s"%n]                                                                                                                                                            
     for pattern in datadct :                                                                                                                                                    
         if pattern in item :                                                                                                                                                     
             p['key1'] = datadct[pattern]["dpath"]                                                                                                        
             p['key2'] = datadct[pattern]["mask"]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
             p['key3'] = storedct[item] 
     n +=1

print patDct
```

Comment: Since I only need the dictionary for the matched pattern, I modified your code for my purpose and yes, it does work. THanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your code, I guess that:

```
patDct = dict()
i = 0
for item in storedct :
    for pattern in datadct :
        if pattern in item :
            i = i + 1
            new_item = {}
            new_item['key1'] = datadct[pattern]["dpath"]
            new_item['key2'] = datadct[pattern]["mask"]
            new_item['key3'] = storedct[item]
            # I used a counter to generate the `mkey` values,
            # not sure you want it that way
            patDct['mkey{0}'.format(i)] = new_item
```

should not be far from your needs...

Comment: Yes, this seem to work with slight modification for my purpose. thanks very much.